# UIActivityIndicatorView Inside TableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to add Spinner to Like button that I have positioned in my tableViewCell. But the problem is spinner is showing outside the tableViewCell.

This is how I implemeneted my code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
myspinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

[myspinner setCenter:cell.like.center];
[cell.like addSubview:myspinner];
```

And when I click using `sender.tag`

```
[myspinner startAnimating];
```

Problem is spinner working but not as I wanted. It's showing outside the cell.

**UPDATE**

With `matt`'s answer It did work. 
also i changed my code like below. inside selector action. `-(void) likeClicked:(UIButton*)sender`

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *myspinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [myspinner setCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(sender.bounds),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(sender.bounds))];
    [sender addSubview:myspinner];
    [myspinner startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code of this form:

```
[myspinner setCenter:cell.like.center];
```

...is never right. The reason is that `myspinner.center` is in its superview's coordinates — that is, in `cell.like` coordinates. But `cell.like.center` is in *its* superview's coordinates. Thus, you are comparing apples with oranges: you are setting a point in terms of another point that lives in a completely different coordinate system. That can only work by accident.

What you want to do is set `myspinner.center` to the center of its superview's *bounds*. Those values are in the *same* coordinate system (here, `cell.like`'s coordinate system).

```
[myspinner setCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cell.like.bounds),
                             CGRectGetMidY(cell.like.bounds))];
```

Comment: Thanks it did work. instead of using `cell.like.bounds.` i have used `sender.bounds` inside my action selector when i click like button.

Comment: Sure, sounds fine. The point is to understand the nature of the coordinate system.

Comment: Yes i got it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

or you may want to use cell's content view to get centre of cell,

```
[myspinner setCenter:cell.contentview.center];
```

this will work too.