# UIActivityIndicatorView goes away when scrolling on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an UIActivityIndicatorView in my UITableViewController in Swift like so:

```
indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

indicator.center = self.view.center

indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

indicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.white

indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.6)

indicator.layer.cornerRadius = 15

self.view.addSubview(indicator)

self.indicator.startAnimating()
```

And this works like a charm, but when its running and I scroll on my UITableView Controller the UIActivityIndicatorView does not scroll with it. How do I get the UIActivityIndicatorView to scroll with the UITableViewController.

Comment: In the case, you can be using UIRefreshControl with UITableViewController

Comment: I dont think UIRefreshControl is what I am looking for here, I need a UIActivityIndicatorView to stay centre in the UITableViewController

Comment: Same Question Here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835754/uiactivityindicatorview-inside-tableview-cell

Comment: Can you provide an answer in swift... I am not sure what I need to adjust here.

Comment: I think that the indicator behind UITableView. Do you try to bring indicator to the front ?  Code: self.view.bringSubview(toFront: indicator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the window

```
let wind = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window! 
wind.addSubview(indicator)
```

To remove

```
indicator.removeFromSuperview()
```

You can also make it inside the vc with

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    indicator.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: indicator.frame.origin.x, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 - 50 + scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and the title seem to ask different things. In the question you ask how to make it move with the scrolling, in the title you ask how not to make it scroll.

There are a few ways to do this (scrolling). 
One way is to implement `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { }` and move the activity indicator when the scroll view (a UITableView is a scrollView after all) scrolls. An other way (which I personally like more) is to put the activity indicator in a table view cell. Cells always scroll with the table view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do is set indicator.center to the center of its superview's bounds. Those values are in the same coordinate system (here, cell.like's coordinate system).

```
indicator.setCenter(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cell.like.bounds),
                             CGRectGetMidY(cell.like.bounds)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the indicator behind UITableView. Do you try to bring indicator to the front?

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: indicator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it scrolls without any problem, so I think there is no error in your code..